# Can't compile js.erb imported modules when trying to test react components with jest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jestjs, erb, babel-jest

I am getting :

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  3 | import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
  4 | import axios from "axios";
> 5 | import I18n from "../../../../i18n-js/index.js.erb";
```

when using jest for my react views, what is the work around to compile .js.erb when testing react views? Can I skip all the statements imported by this library?

Comment: I dont think jest can work with erb honestly. Why is the I18n module inside an erb - can it be a standalone js module?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js , is there any other way of setting up the environment?

Comment: Can you follow the webpack installation guide? (are you using webpacker?) , if you do that you can just import the module normally like you are importing 'react-redux' or 'axios'

Comment: in their github they indicate to add this js.erb file when installing with webpacker:

https://gist.github.com/bazzel/ecdff4718962e57c2d5569cf01d332fe ... how can I import the module normally?

Comment: Sorry you are right. Best to take it with the maintainers maybe, I see someone asked this already but unfortunately no reply https://gist.github.com/bazzel/ecdff4718962e57c2d5569cf01d332fe#gistcomment-3544492

Comment: But indeed maybe you can patch it to not being imported on test environment?

Comment: this other url is offered in the documentation below the previous one i shared:

https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/issues/597

but I get errors when implementing the last message by morgoth , saying `Webpacker can't find i18n/es.js`. when I add them in javascript7i18n-js/es.js.erb

Comment: then I should also find a way of not taking into account all the translations across my views, it also triggers an error when encounters those...

Comment: it was a confusion with the folder naming, I applied  github.com/fnando/i18n-js/issues/597. and it worked. Thank you for the help!